# Flex component - vbox vs group why does one compile, other does not?

Tags: apache-flex, components, flash-builder, advanceddatagrid

Trying to understand why when creating a component in flex (flash builder 4) I am unable to create a component from file->new component and reference "data.", but a slightly different sample works.   This component is going to be used as an advanced data grid renderer.

This one compiles fine:

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" height="100%" width="100%" >
    <s:RichText text="{data.presentingProblemNotes}"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

This one does not compile, does not like the data.presentingProblemNotes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:RichText text="{data.presentingProblemNotes}"/>
</s:Group>
```

The error is on the "data" variable - that it does not exist.

Comment: Tell us exactly what happens when you try to compile it.  What errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mx components, all UIComponent had a 'data' property which was used for item renderers, but that has been removed in Spark components because not all of them needed it.  They now need to extend [DataRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataRenderer.html) for it to work.  In your particular case, you could do this instead:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:RichText text="{data.presentingProblemNotes}"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```